# How to check if an object with specific id exists on a canvas with fabricjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have a function that adds an image on mousedown when clicking a circle inside my canvas. Now every time I click the circle a new image gets added which is not what I want. I'd like some sort of toggle function so it removes the image on second click and adds a new one the third time and so on.

My function at the moment looks like this:

```
cirkel1.on('mousedown', ()=>{
  var imgURL = 'https://i1.wp.com/nypost.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2020/04/pugs-coronavirus.jpg';
  var pugImg = new Image();
  pugImg.onload = function (img) {
    var pug = new fabric.Image(pugImg, {
    width: 350,
    height: 100,
    left: 250,
    top: 70,
    scaleX: .25,
    scaleY: .25
    id: 'testimg'
    });
    canvas.add(pug);
  };
  pugImg.src = imgURL;
});
```

I thought if I check if the `pug` object exists on the canvas I can remove it and only add a new one when no `pug` object exists.

So I tried this:

```
cirkel1.on('mousedown', ()=>{
  var imgURL = 'https://printzelf.nl/new/assets/images/logo_gewoon.png';
  var pugImg = new Image();
  pugImg.onload = function (img) {
    var pug = new fabric.Image(pugImg, {
    width: 350,
    height: 100,
    left: 250,
    top: 70,
    scaleX: .25,
    scaleY: .25
    id: 'testimg'
    });
    canvas.add(pug);
    if(pug > 0){
      console.log('pug exists');
    }else{
      console.log('pug doesnt exist');
    }
  };
  pugImg.src = imgURL;

});
```

But this always go to this part `console.log('pug doesnt exist');` even when there are multiple pugs on the canvas.

So what is the correct way to check this?

Entire code:

https://codepen.io/twan2020/pen/MWbmgqE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to toggle the image visibility then you only need to change the boolean value of its `visible` property.

Rather than hard code each hotspot circle, we'll use a container which can be expanded to add more in future.

```
const hotspots = [
  {
    top: 140,
    left: 230,
    radius: 10,
    fill: '#009fe3',
    id: 'cirkel1',
    hoverCursor: 'pointer',
    selectable: false,
    imgUrl: 'https://i1.wp.com/nypost.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2020/04/pugs-coronavirus.jpg' 
  }
];
```

As the images are loaded when the hotspot is clicked we'll need to keep track of the hotspots that have been activated.

```
const loadedImages = [];
```

Now we're ready to populate the canvas.

```
for (let [idx, props] of hotspots.entries()) {
  let c = new fabric.Circle(props);
  c.class = 'hotspot';
  c.name = 'hotspot-' + idx;
  canvas.add(c);
}
```

There's no magic in this code, we've just added two properties, `class` and `name`, to the hotspot circle before adding it to the canvas. The `class` property will allow us to filter the objects on the canvas so that we only add the `mousedown` handler to the hotspot circles. Having done this we're now ready to add the handler.

```
for (const ho of canvas.getObjects()) {
  // check for 'hotspot' class
  if (ho.class && ho.class === 'hotspot') {
    ho.on('mousedown', () => {
      // check if image was previously loaded
      if (loadedImages.indexOf(ho.name) < 0) {
        // image is not in the array
        // so it needs to be loaded
        // prepare the image properties
        let imgProps = {
          width: 850,
          height: 800,
          left: (ho.left + 30),
          top: (ho.top - 30),
          scaleX: .25,
          scaleY: .25,
          id: 'img-' + ho.name
        };
        var pugImg = new Image();
        pugImg.onload = function (img) {
          var pug = new fabric.Image(pugImg, imgProps);
          canvas.add(pug);
        };
        pugImg.src = ho.imgUrl;
        // update the `loadedImages` array
        loadedImages.push(ho.name);
      } else {
        // image was previously loaded
        for (const o of canvas.getObjects()) {
          // find the correct image on the canvas
          if (o.id && o.id === 'img-' + ho.name) {
            // toggle the visible property
            o.visible = !o.visible;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The `mousedown` handler has two possible execution paths. If the hotspot has not previously been clicked then then image will not have been loaded. We determine this by searching the `loadedImages` array for the value of the hotspot's `name` property. If the name is not found then the image is loaded and the name added to the array. The hotspot `name` is used to set the `id` of the image before it is added to the canvas. If the hotspot is present in the array, then we find the canvas object with the image `id` and toggle the `visible` property.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/danag/pen/MWbvWbo

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I used your code but for some reason I keep getting new pug images when I click the circle, it doesn't remove any old images. Can you take a look what is going wrong? This is how I added it: https://codepen.io/twan2020/pen/GRNvKmX

Comment: The error I get is: `obj is not defined` for: `loadedImages.push(obj.name);`. I'm not sure what the obj name should be. If I use `loadedImages.push(pugImg.name);`, the error is gone, but it still keeps adding new pug images after repeatedly clicking the circle. In stead of add-remove-add-remove etc.

Comment: Change `obj.name` to `ho.name` and the code will work. I've amended the answer, I'm not sure what I was thinking when I typed `obj` instead of `ho`.

Comment: Legend! Thanks works exactly like I need.

Comment: Is it easy to have different images for different hotspots?

Comment: Yes. The image was hard coded in your question so I just used it, but you could just as easily have the image path as a property of the object in the `hotspots` array and reference it. I'll amend the answer to demonstrate it.